# optional CCK field automatically replacing another field in a View

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a content type with 2 CCK text area fields.

The first field is always filled.
The second fields is optional.

Now: I have 2 Views.

In the first View the first field is always displayed.

In the second View the first 2 lines of the first field are displayed. However if the second field is filled, the first field should be ignored.

How can I make this. I need an option in the content type specifying if I should use the second field rather than the first one ? (For the second view)
I hope it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a template for the view and use `if` and `else` statements to only show what you want to be shown.